# Redirect on mobile moving underscore to the front of a url

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile, tablet

We have a code that redirects the user to a different page based on the image name. It works fine on desktop. Today on mobile it started moving an underscore to the front of the URL so we are getting a 404.

Instead of the correct url:

https://e-riggingsandbox-com.3dcartstores.com/_p_3700.html

It is returning this:

_https://e-riggingsandbox-com.3dcartstores.com/p_3700.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                            $("#[value]").click(function(){
                              var img = $(this).find("img");
                              var src = img.attr("src"); 
                              var link = src.toString(); 
                              var linkFinal1 = link.replace('.jpg','');     
                              var linkFinal = linkFinal1.replace('assets/images/icons/','');    
                               $(location).attr("href", "e_" +linkFinal+ ".html");

}); 
});
```

Comment: What is the `"e_"` prior **linkFinal** good for? The above script would turn something like e.g. `https://e-riggingsandbox-com.3dcartstores.com/assets/images/icons/test.jpg` into `e_https://e-riggingsandbox-com.3dcartstores.com/test.html`

Comment: The e was just a test to see if it was the underscore causing the issue. 

The link still works if it is like: https://e-riggingsandbox-com.3dcartstores.com/e_p_3700.html